# Specifying a scanset along with the 'h' width modifier in "swscanf" doesn't work with MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++, scanf

I would like to store the result of reading in a wide string using **swscanf** into a narrow string, but I would like to read **all** input until a new-line character. I have the following simple example code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t* source_string = L"Hello world\n";
    char new_string[100];

    swscanf(source_string, L"%h[^\n]", new_string);
    wprintf(L"%hs", new_string);
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine with gcc, but produces garbage output with MSVC, with a warning:

```
warning C4475: 'swscanf' : length modifier 'h' cannot be used with type field character ']' in format specifier
```

Note that **wprintf** above is just to test and see the output.

Is there a way around this? Is this just MSVC not complying to the actual ANSI C printf/scanf standards?

Answer (score 2):

The scan-set `%[...]` by default uses narrow characters, even for [`swscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwscanf).

The `h` prefix is not supported for `%[...]` in standard C.

Also note that the `h` prefix for `%s` (i.e. `%hs`) is a MSVC extension, it's not defined in standard C.

Comment: I get a warning when removing the h, stating that the first argument to be expected should be a wchar_t*. It therefore is still not working. I use the h prefix for backwards-compatibility as gcc simply ignores it but it forces a narrow string read for MSVC. The problem, however, remains unsolved

Comment: @GaryAllen In short, MS added a non-portable extension to the C language (which it never really cared about anyway) and implemented it inconsistently. I'm not sure there's really much you can do.

Comment: So there's absolutely no way for me to store my result of swscanf in a narrow string using MSVC while also reading until a newline?

Comment: @GaryAllen Not using `swscanf` no. But if you know where the sub-string you want to convert begins and ends then it's relatively straight-forward to extract that part and pass to a conversion function (e.g. [`wcstombs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/wcstombs)).

Comment: My problem is that the format string is being supplied by the caller of my function, and so it is not always the case that they want to store the results of swscanf in a wchar_t*. They may want ints, floats, etc. so I myself do not have control of this output. Its a long story, but basically, the result output is out of my hands. The caller gives me a format string and va_args and I do the nitty gritty for them. Sounds counter-intuitive but its how my setup is working